# Any mathematical software to verify no unique products.

Tags: group-theory, math-software, computer-algebra-systems

Let $D^3= D \times D \times D$ where $D = D_\infty$ where we see $D$ as the group generated by $\mathbb{Z}$ and element $0^*$ of order $2$ such that $0^*n0^*=-n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Letting $n0^*$ be $n^*$ gives the following multiplication: $$nk=n+k \\ nk^*=(n+k)^* \\ n^*k=(n-k)^* \\ n^*k^*=(n-k)$$
Now let $G$ be the subgroup of $D^3$ generated by  $a=(1,0^*,0^*)$ and $b=(0^*,1,1^*)$.

Let $S$ be the set of $14$ elements i.e. $S=$$\left\{ (0,0,2),(0,0,-2),(2^*,1,1^*),(2^*,-1,-1^*),(0^*,1,-1^*),(0^*,-1,1^*),(0^*,-1,-1^*),(1,2^*,0^*),(-1,2^*,0^*),(1,0^*,-2^*),(-1,0^*,2^*),(1,0^*,0^*),(-1,0^*,0^*) \right\} \subset G $

Now $S.S$ consists of $196$ elements and I want to show that every element of $S.S$ also have another representation (i.e. non unique products) as $(a_1,b_1,c_1)(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ where both $(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ are of the form $$E_0: (\text{even}, \text{even},\text{even}) \\ E_1 : (\text{even}^*,\text{odd}, \text{even}^*) \\ E_2 : (\text{odd}, \text{even}^*,\text{even}^*) \\ E_3: (\text{odd}^*,\text{odd}^*,\text{odd})$$ which are basically just the types of elements $G$ consists of.

One way to check it is **by hand**.

I want to know can we check it by some mathematical software or by writing some programme (which I am a dud in). If we can, can somebody help me here, I checked a few with hands, but the list is long and it will be tiresome to check all $196$.

Comment: Perhaps [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) would be useful.

Comment: I'm not clear how the four equations for $nk,nk^*,n^*k,n^*k^*$ define "multiplication in $G$".  I'm not even sure what $G$ is.  You say $S$ is "the set of 14 elements" but also say "S.S consists of 196 elements".  What exactly is $G$, such that it contains $S$ as a subset?

Comment: @hardmath see edit

Comment: Okay.  After the edit, it is clear that $G$ is a group, though the details of $S$ being a subset of $G$ (showing $a,b$ can generate all the fourteen elements) are not.  However if that much is known to you, it suffices to show the $196$ products are unique in $D^3$, since this implies that they are also unique in $G$ (if they exist there).

Comment: @hardmath no we have to show they are 'not' unique in $G$

Comment: Should we restrict $E_0,\,E_1,\,E_2,\,E_3$ to subsets of $G$ (how can I?) or those can be arbitrary of these forms, e.g. $(0,0,0)$? The latter case is here http://pastebin.com/KzEYF6Jr

Comment: no you do not have to restrict as elements of $G$ will have to be of this form from $D^3$. Thanks alot.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin But you missed the string $(0^*,1,1^*)$, can you please repost an edited link with all 196 entries. 27 entries involving  $(0^*,1,1^*)$ are missing in it. It will huge help, bud

Comment: http://pastebin.com/91mw6Ms5 , glad that was helpful. :)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin you should post it as an answer so that I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly the idea of a python program:

- we form list $L$ of $E_1,\,E_2,\,E_3,\,E_4$ where `odd=[1,-1,3,-3]` and `even=[0,2,-2,4,-4]`
- then we compute $xy$ for $(x,y)$ in $L^2$ and store unique products in a dictionary `d`
- then we compute $xy$ for $(x,y)$ in $S^2$ and check whether it is in `d`

The code is here http://pastebin.com/KzEYF6Jr and the result with $(0^*,1,1^*)$ included is here http://pastebin.com/91mw6Ms5 .

P.S. Please don't accept this too soon as I want to know if there is a software, which is a fishing-rod, but not the fish.

Comment: yeah that would be really helpful

Comment: But you have pasted the code that is missing $27$ entries. Update the new one you generated

Comment: I am sorry, but I asked the question wrong. I want that any elements of $S.S$ say $ab$ s.t. $ a,b /in S $ can be written as $c.d$ where $ c,d /in S$ different from $ a$ or $ b $. Can it be done by the same process. I ll edit the question later, as I m on phone ryt now. Thanx.

Comment: $(0,0,0)$ is not an element of $S$, it is the identity of group, so $ab=e.ab$ is always true, which is mosyly the case in your list. I am sorry for asking wrong.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/B4EDSTjZ